# The Search button is not working in elasticsearch using Tire

Tags: haml

whenever i try to write a word to search for it, i get nothing as if the button of Seach is diasbled. i indexed my blogpost already.

```
this is for search
%h1 My Blog

= form_tag blog_posts_path, method: :get do 
  %p    
= text_field_tag :query, params[:query]
= submit_tag "Search", name: nil
- @blog_posts.each do |blog_post|
  %p
    %b= link_to blog_post.title, blog_post

  %p= blog_post.content

  %p{style: "float: right;"}
    = link_to "Delete", blog_post, method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this post?"
    %hr{style: "clear: both;"}

%br

= link_to 'New Post', new_blog_post_path
```

and this indexing
marina@ubuntu:~/project$ rake db:setup
Generated indexes for BlogPost

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting the `text_field_tag` and the `submit_tag` underneath the `form_tag`, in your code these are sibling nodes.

```
%p
  = form_tag blog_posts_path, method: :get do   
    = text_field_tag :query, params[:query]
    = submit_tag "Search", name: nil
```